# Why does find's -exec only executes on one result?

Tags: find

Here's what I checked:

`find mydir -maxdepth 2 -name .project -or -name .classpath`

gives output:

```
mydir/.project
mydir/.classpath
```

Meanwhile

`find mydir -maxdepth 2 -name .project -or -name .classpath -exec echo {} \;`

gives output:

```
mydir/.classpath
```

so only 1 found item is listed, why?

xargs works as expected:

`find mydir -maxdepth 2 -name .project -or -name .classpath | xargs -I {} echo {};`

prints:

```
mydir/.project
mydir/.classpath
```

Am I missing something about `-exec`?

Comment: 3 comments in one: `-o` is much more portable than `-or`, and means the same thing.  I assume the `-exec echo` is for the sake of illustrating `-exec` only, since `-print` would be much better otherwise.  For safety reasons, avoid piping `find` to `xargs` unless you have `find -print0 | xargs -0`.  If you don't have that, use `-exec \;` or `-exec +` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `find` expression is basically a list of predicates (boolean conditions).  In almost all boolean contexts, including `find` expressions, the `AND` operator takes precedence over `OR`.  If I add some parentheses to illustrate the precedence rules explicitly, your second `find` expression is logically equivalent to

```
( -name .project ) OR ( -name .classpath AND -exec echo)
```

In order to get your desired behavior, you need

```
find mydir -maxdepth 2 \( -name .project -o -name .classpath \) -exec ... {} \;
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, Does this mean that I can have different `-exec`'s for different conditions?

Comment: @gasan Yes you can

Comment: For example, see [Change all folder permissions with one command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349063/80216).