# Change all folder permissions with 1 command

Tags: centos, chmod

Within my web application directory, how can I change all my folder permissions to `rwxr-xr-x` (755)? And how can I change all file permissions to `rw-r--r--` (644)? I want to change all folders and files including sub-sub files and folders.

I know the following command would change all files and folders but I want to discrimate between a file and a folder.

```
chmod -R 755 ./my_web_app_project
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to do exactly what you want with one `find` command is

```
find my_web_app_project '(' -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ';' ')' -o '(' -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ';' ')'
```

`-o` means OR. 
This command processes all objects in the project tree
that are of type “file” *or* type “directory”,
and executes different commands based on which type each object is.

You can make this slightly more efficient
by replacing the semicolons (`';'`) with plus signs (`+`);
this tells `find`
to run `chmod 644` once, with all the plain files’ names as arguments,
and to run `chmod 755` once, with all the directories’ names as arguments.

By the way, you don’t need to say `./`
for anything other than running a program in the current directory
(although it does occasionally come in handy
for manipulating files whose names begin with some special characters).

---

I wonder what your permissions look like now
(before running a recursive tree-wide `chmod`). 
Files generally don’t get their execute permission bits turned on
unless they actually executable programs,
or you’ve accidentally done something like `chmod -R 755`. 
Directories generally don’t get their execute permission bits turned off
unless you’ve done something catastrophic like `chmod -R 644`. 
If you have badly messed up permissions
because you have done an ill-advised `chmod -R` with a numeric mode,
ignore this section
and stick with the command at the beginning of this answer.

But, if your permissions are generally sane,
and you just want to impose a standard of
read/write permissions for the user,
and read-only permissions for everybody else (group and world),
you can do

```
chmod -R +rX,u+w,go-w my_web_app_project
```

in which

- `+rX` means `+r,+X` (note that the `X` is capitalized — this is important).

  - `+r` means set read permission for user, group and other.
  - `+X` means set execute permission for user, group and other
    ***if it is currently set for any of them*** or if the object is a directory.
- `u+w` means set write permission for user.
- `go-w` means turn off write permission for group and other.

#### Summary of some key points:

- Of course you can `chmod` only things that you own
  (unless you’re privileged) and that are not read-only. 
  If there are things in your directory that you cannot `chmod`,
  any of these commands will cause an error.
- The `find` commands will not do anything to things
  that are not directories or files (e.g., named pipes).
- The `find` command with `-exec chmod 755 {} +` may fail
  if you do not already have read and execute permission to all folders
  under your top level directory.
- The `chmod -R +rX,u+w,go-w` command will

  - set all directories to mode 755,
  - ignore symbolic links,
  - for all other file types (including, e.g., named pipes):

    - set it to 755 if it already has at least one `x` bit; otherwise,
    - set it to 644.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You need two commands.

```
find ./my_web_app_project -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./my_web_app_project -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Edit:

See G-Man's answer, as it is much more correct.

Comment: ... but type it all on one line ;-)

Comment: Ha! Yes, that would work :)